# Share internet through Dell laptop Windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, internet-sharing

I have Windows 7 installed on my Dell Inspiron laptop.  I want to share internet on my home through wireless!

I can share files but I can not share Internet!
How to do it?

ADSL D-Link

**I have wired connection (and using dial to connect)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a wired connection to your laptop, you can use it to share your internet wirelessly, by creating a wireless hotspot...

**[VirtualRouter](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)** or [**Connectify**](http://connectify.me/) will do this.

> Virtual Router is a free, open source software based router for PCs running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2. Using Virtual Router, users can wirelessly share any internet connection (Wifi, LAN, Cable Modem, Dial-up, Cellular, etc.) with any Wifi device (Laptop, Smart Phone, iPod Touch, iPhone, Android Phone, Zune, Netbook, wireless printer, etc.) These devices connect to Virtual Router just like any other access point, and the connection is completely secured using WPA2 (the most secure wireless encryption.)

Another option is an **ad-hoc network**.  Step-by-step tutorial from Microsoft:

> [Set up a computer-to-computer (ad hoc) network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network)

I've used ad-hoc networks successfully to share Internet wirelessly.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about VirtualRouter.

Comment: Last I checked VirtualRouter (and all similar variants) need a certain class of wireless card that is able to operate in AP (a.k.a. master or hostednetwork) mode. Not all can. If the wireless card doesn't support that, it won't work at all.

Comment: @studiohack  It doesn't work and failed!

Comment: @Aseman: the other thing to try is to set up an ad-hoc network...will update post.

Comment: @studiohack Thanks! I created ad hoc before but how to share internet?

Comment: @Aseman: I believe you want to enable ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) for the ad-hoc network...

Comment: @studiohack I want other people in my home network be able to browse Internet page! no matter how!

Comment: @Aseman: You need to have both wired and wireless Internet capabilities on your laptop, then create an ad-hoc network on that machine.  It needs to use the wired connection to give the wireless-ad-hoc network Internet...

Comment: @studiohack yes I have, I created an ad-hoc network and share Enabled ICS for all network but it did not work!!!