# How do I make my desktop a wifi hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking

I want to connect my Android phone with wireless to my desktop PC to use it for downloading apps from the Google Play Store. My PC has this device [image]

And this is connected to the back of CPU through a wire. I don't know what this device is . How do I make my PC a WiFi hotspot to connect to my phone ?

Comment: Just to make sure we know the question... You want to download applications (directly) to your computer, then install them on your phone? This isn't necessary due to the Play Store having the ability to recognize your phone, tied to your account... You can find an app in the store and tell it to install and it will auto-magically begin downloading onto your phone.

Comment: No . I want to use my desktops internet connection on my Android phone to download apps on my phone through play store . Some apps are big in file size .

Comment: The device that you gave a picture of looks to be a wireless router, you should connect to that.

Comment: How ? I havent installed any wireless driver on my PC . How do I make my desktop a wifi hotspot .

Comment: I tried searching for WIFI networks from my phone . It doesnt show anything .

Comment: Can you provide me the model number of that Ruckus device? Perhaps it's actually not a Wireless router but actually your modem

Comment: Ruckus MM2211 .

Comment: DO you even have a wifi card on your desktop? because they dont usually come with one. If all you are interested in is to download apps from playstore, all you need it to login to the website with the same email id you configured on your phone. Any app that you click to install on the website will be wirelessly delivered

Comment: I know that method . But the speeds are terrible and 3G is very expensive in my country . Therefore I need the wifi method .

Comment: Why don't you use that Ruckus MM2211 as WIFI hotspot? Regarding to its [manual](http://www.ceralvoip.com/MM2211UserGuide_072006.pdf) it  is able to do this.

Comment: I searched the word " hostspot " in the manual . 0 results .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share internet through dell laptop Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/259280/share-internet-through-dell-laptop-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

The "Ruckus MM2211" device you have is a wireless router. It'll be connected to your PC via an Ethernet cable.

This means that you don't need to connect your Android phone to the Internet via your PC, you can just set up the wireless functionality of the Ruckus and connect your Android directly to it.

Instructions on how to set up wireless on the Ruckus MM2211 are available here: https://support.ruckuswireless.com/documents/22-mm2211-dz-quick-start-guide/download (You'll want to follow the instructions under "Connect and Configure Your Ruckus MM2211 Gateway", particularly steps 5, 6 and 7).

Answer (score 0):

This is all I could fine in terms of tethering your phone to your PC using your PC's internet rather than the phones:

[Reverse Tether App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.littlelan.ReverseTether.Paid&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to create an ad-hoc wireless network, share your wired connection to your wireless one, and connect to the wireless network from your phone.

You didn't mention what Operating System you have, but [here's a Lifehacker article on how to do it with Windows 7](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot)

There are also links in that article for how to do it with Windows XP, and Mac OSX.

**Edit:** This will only work if your desktop has a wireless network adapter.

Comment: You're assuming he has a wifi card on his desktop though... which I doubt is true

Comment: I tried the Life Hacker method . It only shows the top 4 options . Not the 5th one " Set up wireless ad hoc "

Comment: @Wescrock Oops. I misread the title- skipped right over the word "desktop"

Comment: @Nikhil - What you are trying to do is not a common scenario... Normally, it is reversed (using the android data plan to connect a laptop to the internet.)... I think you may be stuck with my above answer for the quickest solution.

Comment: So I need to get a wireless card for my desktop ?

Comment: No... look at my answer above... there is an app for your phone that will tether your phone to your PC